# Update passed variables in fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a fullcalendar where I can filter events result based on a select input (multiple):

```
<select id="ids" name="ids[]" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="1" selected> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="btn-filter">Apply</button>
```

Default view is with OPTION 1 selected. When load the page, fullcalendar can retrieve correctly my selection.

If I'll select other option (OPTION 2 for example) and click the button filter, fullcalendar refresh but still pass only OPTION 1 (I see it in debug console Firefox):

FIREFOX CONSOLE:

```
array_ids[]:    1
start:  2019-06-01T00:00:00
end:    2019-07-01T00:00:00
```

This is the piece of code of fullcalendar

```
events: {
            url: './get-events.php',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                array_ids: $("#ids").val()
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
        },
```

This is the button to refresh calendar:

```
  $('#btn-filter').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

    });
```

It seems fullcalendar store only the first value when page loads: `array_ids: $("#ids").val()`

EDIT: ok I've modified in this way:

```
   events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {

           $.ajax({
             url: './get-events.php',
             data: { "array_ids": $("#ids").val(), "start": moment(start).format(), "end": moment(end).format() },
             cache: false,
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (data) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
             }
           });

        },
```

Now all select option are passed...but.... calendar stop render the result... remains empty....but watching console firefox I see the data are collected correctly....only doesn't show on fullcalendar!

Comment: See my answer below for a fix to your original version. Your modified version isn't working because you aren't telling fullCalendar the new events. Think about it - rerenderEvents just re-displays what's already there. The new event data is within `data`...but you aren't using it. As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function) you have to use the provided callback function in order to tell fullCalendar about the new events, it doesn't happen by magic. `success: function (data) {
                callback(data);
             }` would work in that situation

Comment: ...or potentially you might need `success: function (data) { callback(JSON.parse(data)); }` if jQuery doesn't already detect that the output from PHP is JSON. But anyway you don't need this complexity, since you can fix it much more simply using my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are passing static data to fullCalendar. When you write

```
data: {
  array_ids: $("#ids").val()
},
```

you give to fullCalendar the value of `$("#ids").val()` *at that moment in time* - i.e. at the moment when you created the calendar. You simply pass the value once. fullCalendar receives and stores that value and re-uses it whenever it contacts your server. It does not know where the value came from, and has no way to update it. That's just the way  JavaScript works (and other most programming languages in fact) - variables are normally passed by value, not by reference (and in any case you don't have a reference here, since you just passed the output of a function directly).

As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) (in the section entitled *"Dynamic data parameter"*), if you want fullCalendar to check for a new data value each time it contacts the server, you need to give it a way to do that. The way you do that is this:

Instead of passing a simple value for your data, give fullCalendar a callback function. This means fullCalendar can run that function every time, and it will return a new value based on current data.

```
data: function() { // a function that returns an object
  return {
    array_ids: $("#ids").val()
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify me the problem  @ADyson . When you answer me I have a few second before, edited my post with a partial solution using ajax that partially works (but nothing rendered...) so your solution is better and fully working!

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini no problem! Yes this is the best way to solve it. Remember to always read the documentation in full - it often contains the answer already, as in this case! But above in the other comments I have also added a little explanation of why your second attempt didn't work properly, just so you understand that as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again @ADyson

Comment: sorry for another request: i'm trying to migrate to fullcalendar 4.x so data is renamed to extraParams. Now extraParams doens't manage the variable as array...but as a string. For example if I select option 1 and 2....extraParams convert it into string: 1,2 instead array(1,2). Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you ask a new question about it please, with some code and a proper example, formatted nicely so I can read and understand it. This is a separate issue from what this question is discussing. Thanks. Tag me here with a link to your new question when it's ready.

Comment: Hi this is my new post thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987425/fullcalendar-migrate-from-3-x-to-4-x-extraparams-doesnt-manipulate-multiple-inp