# Fullcalendar migrate from 3.x to 4.x extraParams doesn't manipulate multiple input as array

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to migrate from fullcalendar 3.x to 4.x

```
<select id="ids" name="ids[]" class="form-control" multiple>
 <option value="1" selected> Option 1</option>
 <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
 <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="btn-filter">Apply</button>
```

In 3.x version the `data` parameter inside `events` are correctly managed as array:

This is my FIREFOX CONSOLE:

```
array_ids[]:
    0: 1
    1: 2
start:  2019-06-01T00:00:00
end:    2019-07-01T00:00:00
```

Piece of code:

```
  events: {
        url: './get-events.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: function() { // a function that returns an object
          return {
            array_ids: $("#ids").val()
           };
        }
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
    },
```

Now after converting into 4.x with this code:

```
         events: {
            url: './get-events.php',
            cache: false,
            method: 'POST',      <--- type -> method
            extraParams: function() { 
              return {
                array_ids: $("#ids").val()
              };
            }
        },
```

my FIREFOX CONSOLE show:

```
array_ids: 1,2             //as string
```

See attachment ( array_ids is renamed in this example but the logic is the same)
[image]

Comment: Exactly what is this log output the result of, and when does it run? I see no console log commands in your code.

Comment: I see XHR inside firefox console on load page or when i'll apply the button filter. I see into tab PARAMETERS for page loaded "get-events.php"

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: I can reproduce this. v3 behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/m4t6jdgk/ . v4 behaviour: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jjJVGm . Looks like it's internal to fullCalendar, so you probably need to [report a bug](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) . There's nothing I can do about it unfortunately.

Comment: As a workaround you might have to use the events-as-a-function option instead, then you've got full control over how the data is sent to the server.

Comment: ok thanks i just reported the bug!

Comment: Actually i'll prefer this workaroud in the get-events.php page. explode(",", $_POST['array_ids']);

Comment: Yeah that works. I just thought you might not want to alter your server-side code to accommodate a fullCalendar bug. I suppose it depends if any other clients also tries to read your event feed (e.g. maybe you'd have a mobile app or automated service or something which might use it, and you wouldn't want to have to change those too. But if that's not a problem then it's a reasonable solution).